# Why is data not evenly distributed among partitions when a partitioning key is not specified?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is this explanation still valid in Kafka 10?

In Kafka producer, a partition key can be specified to indicate the destination partition of the message. By default, a hashing-based partitioner is used to determine the partition id given the key, and people can use customized partitioners also.
To reduce # of open sockets, in 0.8.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1017), when the partitioning key is not specified or null, a producer will pick a random partition and stick to it for some time (default is 10 mins) before switching to another one. So, if there are fewer producers than partitions, at a given point of time, some partitions may not receive any data. To alleviate this problem, one can either reduce the metadata refresh interval or specify a message key and a customized random partitioner. For more detail see this thread http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201310.mbox/%3CCAFbh0Q0aVh%2Bvqxfy7H-%2BMnRFBt6BnyoZk1LWBoMspwSmTqUKMg%40mail.gmail.com%3E

From here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whyisdatanotevenlydistributedamongpartitionswhenapartitioningkeyisnotspecified?

Answer (score 0):

The new producer has changed to use round-robin policy. That's to say, messages will be delivered to all partitions evenly if no keys are specified.

Comment: Given null key, I think the old producer also uses round robin policy. It produces to one partition for 10 minutes and then change to another. So at some point the data is not evenly distributed if number of thread of producer is, let's say, 1. The new implementation makes the records evenly distributed across all partition?

Comment: Old producer randomly picks a partition if no key is given and cache contains no partition info for the topic, so it's very unlikely to behavior in a round-robin manner. See kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.getPartition method